# Desempenho em Javascript: switch ou if aninhado?

Tags: javascript, if, desempenho, switch

Qual das duas alternativas provê o melhor desempenho em Javascript: switch ou if aninhado?

```
if {
  ...
} else {
  if {
    ...
  } else {
    if {
      ...
    } else {
      ...
    }
  }
}
```

ou

```
switch(expression) {
    case n:
        code block
        break;
    case n:
        code block
        break;
    default:
        default code block
}
```

Comment: Por que negativaram a pergunta dele? Não é ampla e facilmente explicável com benchmarks, sem ter bases em opiniões. Eu positivei, a pergunta é relevante. =)

Comment: Eu não negativei, mas o benchmark poderia ser o pressuposto da pergunta. E a pergunta ser sobre o porquê dos resultados.

Comment: Qual a pergunta afinal? a única frase que existe na postagem não me diz exatamente o que é a pergunta, por mais que ela seja intuitiva. Poderia ser, qual dos dois é mais bonito no código, qual dos dois é mais lento, qual dos dois é mais rápido, qual dos dois é mais usado... enfim. Por esse motivo eu negativei.

Comment: @Marciano Editei pra deixar mais claro, mas mesmo antes já falava em desempenho.

Answer (score 8):

Por incrível que pode parecer, o `else-if` é o mais performático dentre as opções possíveis.

[Neste](http://jsperf.com/switch-if-else/10) e [neste](http://jsperf.com/switch-if-else) benchmark, analisamos que o Chrome possui um desempenho superior em condições `else-if` *quase que* independente da versão do navegador.

O benchmark é um avaliador técnico. Pela lógica, o `else-if` é uma condição simples e explítica, enquanto o `switch`, por mais trivial que possa parecer, possui critérios (mais) complexos por trás – ele é sensível e *inteligente* porque consegue tomar decisões implícitas, como é o caso do controlador `default` e os `case` sem valor. Um `else-if`, por exemplo, não consegue, naturalmente, determinar um caso padrão – você deve fazer isso sem subjeção; você deve fazer isso indicando explicitamente no seu código.

Simplificando, o `switch` possui um algoritmo mais complexo por trás para que o possibilite tomar algumas decisões sem que tenhamos que dar explicações. Ele é mais autônomo; mais independente. O `else-if` faz isso somente se alguém assim o disser.

Veja o [seguinte exemplo](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch):

```
var foo = 1;
switch (foo) {
    case 0:
    case 1:
    case 2:
    case 3:
        alert('yes');
        break;
    default:
        alert('not');
}
```

Mesmo que não usemos o `default`, como no exemplo a seguir, a implementação da função `switch` estará preparada caso formos o utilizar. Portanto, ele é convexo – se não usarmos algo, estará lá de qualquer jeito, e isso exige hardware; isso exige braço. Veja:

```
var foo = 1;
switch (foo) {
    case 0:
    // [...]
}
```

Um `else-if`, por outro lado, não possui esses "coringas". Ele só vai tratar o que você disser para ele o fazer, do contrário, ele é hostil. Em suma, ainda no `else-if`, não existem coisas preparadas que podem "engordurar" a sua solução caso você não a utilize – e isso o torna mais simples e *quase* que consequentemente mais performático.

#### Contextualização prática

O `switch` possui as chaves reservadas `case`, `default` e et cetera. Se pararmos para pensar, ele precisa saber o que fazer quando o desenvolvedor chamar por `default` e quando atribuir condições aos `case`s.

Caso o desenvolvedor não atribua nada à `default`, sem problemas! Ele possui um padrão de tratamento quando isso ocorrer – e o que esse padrão demanda? Mais código, mais lógica e finalmente *mais performance*. Como eu disse, o `else-if` é mais objetivo e "burro" – ele precisa que você explique tudo o que deve fazer porque ele não é inteligente o suficiente para tomar decisões autônomas, o que diverge de um `switch`.

#### Sobre processadores JavaScript

Como você pode perceber, o benchmark mencionado anteriormente consiste no navegador da Google, o Chrome, que possui o [motor V8](https://developers.google.com/v8/) como processador.

Cada motor possui um mecanismo próprio de compilação, sendo que esses mecanismos podem assumir compromissos mais ou menos performáticos dependendo de sua estruturação e implementação. O ponto que eu quero chegar é que, no caso do Chrome, o `else-if` é "imbatível" porque por nos camarins as coisas funcionam de um jeito específico que dá esse mérito à ele.

Por outro lado, [neste benchmark](http://jsperf.com/switch-vs-if-else-vs-ifs/3), ele avalia como o `switch` sendo uma opção de maior performance se relacionado à cadeias de `if`s no Firefox. O porquê disso? Compilador. Mais que a implementação do `switch` lá, a filosofia de desenvolvimento é outra.

#### `else-if` ou `switch`, afinal?

Na minha opinião, pelo fato do Chrome [ser mais utilizado que o Firefox e qualquer outro navegador](http://www.w3schools.com/browsers/browsers_stats.asp), eu iria de `else-if` no tema *performance*.

O `switch`, em alguns casos, é mais semântico e a sua aplicabilidade se destaca: se a sua procura for essa – o que foge do escopo da pergunta –, então vá com ele.

#### Mentiras em potencial

Para fortalecer a minha resposta, antecipo algo que o usuário [Maniero](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/101/maniero) mencionou nos comentários: *benchmarks são extremamente relativos*, principalmente de navegadores modernos. Se você visualizar os benchmarks que compartilhei, é fácil identificar uma oscilação bem grande nos resultados ao longo das versões dos navegadores.

Onde quero chegar é: não que benchmarks não sejam confiáveis, mas eles *não são totalmente confiáveis*. Como repliquei ao Maniero, o ideal é utilizarmos estatísticas como um pouco de base e referência, mas não como a solução definitiva da paz.

Comment: Executei o benchmark aqui e ele mostrou que a diferença entre switch e if-else é de 0.2% (as vezes para um, as vezes para outro). Negligenciável. Pode mostrar por que "Chrome possui um desempenho superior em condições else-if"?

Comment: Para mim o switch ganhou... :p

Comment: Estão vocês usando Firefox? Se sim, me desculpem – deixei ele passar despercebido. Fiz uma abordagem melhor da minha tese (?). Vejam agora.

Comment: @GuilhermeOderdenge Executei usando o Chrome 35.

Comment: @GuilhermeBernal Executei também com o Chrome 35 e tive 685kk ops/sec no `else-if` contra 587kk ops/sec no `switch`. Até onde eu sei – e também segundo o jsperf – *higher is better*.

Comment: Liar! Liar! Liar! Benchmarks are liars! *Benchmarks* só funcionam em condições específicas. Sem um bom controle do ambiente o *benchmark* pode variar muito. E um *browser*, principalmente moderno, é um ambiente muito instável. É possível fazer *benchmark* nele, mas não é tarefa fácil.  Seria legal existir algo canônico de como fazer *benchmark* em *browsers*. A edição melhorou o entendimento. E estatísticas de uso também são mentirosas. Tem para todo gosto: https://www.netmarketshare.com/browser-market-share.aspx?qprid=0&qpcustomd=0 Só confio nas estatísticas de acesso do meu site. E olhe lá.

Comment: @bigown Eu concordo com você – estatísticas são "mentirosas". O ponto é: o ideal é sempre *tentarmos* chegar o mais perto possível das coisas – e eu acho que o benchmark *ajuda* nisso: ele não precisa nada, mas ajuda.

Comment: +1 pelo jsperf.