# Qual a diferença entre else e elseif?

Tags: php, condição

Queria saber qual a diferença entre `else` e `elseif` em PHP, e quando devo usar um ou outro.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

O `else` não tem condição a verificar e é usado no final/depois de uma série de `if` / `elseif`, como "caso geral".

O `elseif`, à semelhança do `if`,  usa-se em casos onde é necessário verificar a autenticidade de uma condição. Assim em vez de multiplos `if`, usa-se *n* `elseif`, e no final o caso geral dentro do `else`.

**Exemplo**, se tiveres muitas condições:

```
if ($a == 'hoje') { //fazer algo }
elseif ($a == 'amanhã') { // fazer algo diferente }
else { // todos os outros casos }
```

**Se** o valor de `$a` for `hoje` somente a primeira condição se verifica e as outras linhas não serão corridas.

**Se** o valor de `$a` for `amanhã` a primeira linha dá `false`, ele testa a segunda condição e dá `true`. Somente a segunda condição se verifica e as outras linhas não serão corridas.

**Se** o valor de `$a` for `ontem` as duas primeiras condições falham (dão `false` e ele só corre o código do `else`.

**Notas:**

O `elseif` é muito útil para evitar verificações longas uma vez que **as condições excluem-se** (se uma der `true` as outras nem são testadas/corridas).

Em casos de muitas condições pode ser melhor usar o `switch` [como o @Zuul referiu](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/57800/129).
Porém esta estrutura `if`/`elseif`/`else` permite verificações diferentes em cada condição, enquanto que o `switch` verifica somente uma variável que pode ter valores diferentes.

Exemplo que o `switch` não consegue reproduzir:

```
if ($a == 'hoje') { //fazer algo }
elseif ($a == 'amanhã' && $mes == 'janeiro') { // fazer algo diferente }
elseif ($a == 'hoje' && $diaSemana == 'segunda') { // fazer algo diferente }
else { // todos os outros casos }
```

Comment: Como o @Sergio falou é isso mesmo o else não tem condição, o else if normalmente é utilizado quando você quer criar outra condição alem do if superior.

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta!

Comment: Ainda na tradução o elseif pode ser traduzido para senãose (senão se) enquanto o else apenas para senão.

Answer (score 17):

Podemos ler na [documentação](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.elseif.php) que:

> `elseif`, como seu nome sugere, é uma combinação de `if` e `else`. Como o  `else`, ele estende um comando `if` para executar uma instrução diferente no caso da condição do `if` original vir a ser avaliada como `FALSE`.
>
> No entanto, ao contrário de `else`, ele executará aquela expressão alternativa somente se a expressão condicional do `elseif` for avaliada como `TRUE`.

Em suma, `elseif` introduz novas condições na nossa estrutura de controlo.

## Exemplo

```
if ($a > $b) {               // entra se verdadeiro
    echo "a é maior que b";
} else if ($a == $b) {        // entra se verdadeiro
    echo "a é igual a b";
} else {                     // se chegou aqui, vai sempre entrar
    echo "a é menor que b";
}
```

## Aplicação prática

Este tipo de verificação intermédia é útil para os casos onde temos a necessidade de verificar duas ou mais condições antes de chegar ao valor "por defeito".

De notar que quando as verificações são muitas, o `if~elseif~else` acaba por ser ineficiente, tornando-se preferível o uso de uma estrutura de control [`switch()`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php).

Ver esta [pergunta relacionada](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/21992/223) que fala sobre o uso de `switch` ao invés de múltiplos `elseif` que apesar de se referir a JavaScript, aplica-se a PHP em termos de performance.

## Convenções

Em PHP, o `else if` também pode ser escrito como `elseif`, ambos estão corretamente declarados e produzem o efeito pretendido. De notar que o mesmo não se verifica em outras linguagens:

Ver no [Ideone](http://ideone.com/czsr2m).

- **Exemplo:**

  ```
  $a = $b = 1;
  if ($a > $b) {                // entra se verdadeiro
      echo "a é maior que b";
  } else if ($a == $b) {        // entra se verdadeiro
      echo "a é igual a b";
  } else {                      // se chegou aqui, vai sempre entrar
      echo "a é menor que b";
  }

  echo PHP_EOL;

  $a = ($b = 1)+1;
  if ($a > $b) {               // entra se verdadeiro
      echo "a é maior que b";
  } elseif ($a == $b) {        // entra se verdadeiro
      echo "a é igual a b";
  } else {                     // se chegou aqui, vai sempre entrar
      echo "a é menor que b";
  }
  ```
- **Saída:**

  ```
  a é igual a b  
  a é maior que b
  ```

> **Atenção**, para cada regra uma exceção, saber mais detalhes sobre as diferenças entre `elseif` e `else if` [nesta pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/57891/223).

## Advertências

Convém salientar que o uso de um `else if` não produz o mesmo efeito que múltiplos `if` em alguns casos. Pegando num exemplo de manipulação do valor utilizado na condição, pode-se ilustrar a falha da seguinte forma:

Ver no [Ideone](http://ideone.com/M4ZXO0).

- **Exemplo:**

  ```
  /* Pretende-se apurar onde se encaixa o A
   * em relação a grupos de 10 para fazer algo,
   * neste exemplo um "echo", e depois incrementar A
   * para prosseguir.
   */
  $a = 20;

  if ($a>=1  AND $a<=20) {
      echo "A no primeiro grupo";
      $a++;
  }

  echo PHP_EOL;

  if ($a>=21  AND $a<=30) {
      echo "A no segundo grupo";
      $a++;
  }
  ```
- **Saída:**

  ```
  A no primeiro grupo  // correto
  A no segundo grupo   // errado, A no primeiro grupo e depois queriamos prosseguir
  ```

Apenas um exemplo, básico, mas que reflete o fato de que com um `else if` este cenário nunca iria acontecer porque a segunda condição nunca seria avaliada.

E isto leva-nos para o desempenho da aplicação:

```
// vai verificar
if ($a > $b) {
    echo "a é maior que b";
}

// vai verificar
if ($a == $b) {
    echo "a é igual a b";
}

// vai verificar
if ($a < $b) {
    echo "a é menor que b";
}
```

Em suma, a aplicação vai realizar todas as condições, mesmo não precisando delas, e é aqui que o `else if` ajuda a lidar com a questão, pois após uma condição avaliada para verdadeiro, as restantes são ignoradas evitando assim o consumo desnecessário de recursos!

Answer (score 9):

Todo mundo já explicou bem o que é. Vou tentar mostrar de outra forma.

```
if ($valor < 10) {
    $total += $valor
} elseif ($total < 20) {
    $total += $valor * 1.1;
} elseif ($total < 30) {
    $total += $valor * 1.2;
} else {
    $total += $valor * 1.3;
}
```

Veja agora:

```
if ($valor < 10) {
    $total += $valor
}
if ($total < 20) {
    $total += $valor * 1.1;
}
if ($total < 30) {
    $total += $valor * 1.2;
}
if ($total >= 30) {
    $total += $valor * 1.3;
}
```

No primeiro caso apenas um `if` será executado. O bloco do `if` trabalha em regime de [curto-circuito](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Avalia%C3%A7%C3%A3o_de_curto-circuito), ou seja, quando uma dos sub-blocos dele é executado, os demais não são mais executados. Eles são excludentes. Então o resultado dele será de acordo com o primeiro bloco que a condição resultar em `true`. Já no segundo exemplo, todos eles poderão executar se cada um deles individualmente resultar em `true`. Poderia até ser sua intenção, mas não parece ser. Neste caso se o valor for menos que 10, ele executará 3 vezes e gerará um valor acumulado que provavelmente não deveria fazer.

Note que o oposto também é verdadeiro. Se você precisa que todos os `ifs` sejam avaliados
independente do resultado dos anteriores, obviamente eles precisam ficar independentes, não podem constituir um único bloco.
Se ficou em dúvida, faça um teste de mesa, com ambos usando uma valor abaixo de 10. Qualquer valor abaixo de 30 produzirá um resulto errado quando os `ifs` são independentes.

Quando você usa o `elseif` você cria uma estrutura única que funciona de forma integrada.

Claro que é possível usar apenas `if` e `else` e obter o mesmo resultado, mas olha como fica esquisito:

```
if ($valor < 10) {
    $total += $valor
} else {
    if ($total < 20) {
        $total += $valor * 1.1;
    } else {
        if ($total < 30) {
            $total += $valor * 1.2;
        } else {
            if ($total >= 30) {
                $total += $valor * 1.3;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/PHP/Syntax/IfElse.php).

A forma usando o `elseif` pode ser vista como [*syntax sugar*](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/A%C3%A7%C3%BAcar_sint%C3%A1tico) para a forma com `else` com `ifs` aninhados. E é um importante para manter a sanidade do seu código, especialmente se tiver muitos sub-blocos de execução.

Curiosamente acho que seria mais fácil entender se as pessoas aprendessem primeiro o `elseif`. Porque o `else` pode ser interpretado como `elseif (true)`. Ou seja, se nenhuma das condições anteriores forem falsas, então tenta esta, que sempre é a última, e ela certamente vai executar porque o `if` está esperando por um `true` para executar, e neste caso, é garantido que o resultado seja este.

Obviamente não faz sentido ter mais que um `else` ou ter um `else` antes de um `elseif`, afinal é garantido que ele será executado se chegar até ele e depois o circuito será fechado e nenhum outro sub-bloco sequer será avaliado.

Se você já entende o `switch` pode ver o `elseif` de forma semelhante. Claro que o `elseif` permite condições mais poderosas, o `case` permite apenas comparação de igualdade de uma valor único. O `elseif` é *short-circuit*, o `case` não é, se você não colocar um `break`, ele tentará avaliar os demais. Mas as construções são semelhantes. Você usa ambas se as comparações estão relacionados. Não faz sentido, mesmo que funcione, colocar comparações sem relação no mesmo bloco.

Comment: É preciso ter cuidado nesses casos porque se o primeiro `if` envolver os demais resultados os outros nunca serão executados. Por exemplo no caso de colocar primeiro o `if ($total < 30)` e depois os outros, os outros 2 não seriam executados nunca.

Comment: +1 pelo "excludentes"

Answer (score 6):

Apenas para esclarecer caso ainda tenha duvidas, esse é o if padrão :

```
if (condicao) 
    { 
        procedimento
    }
    else
    {
        if (outra codicao) 
        { 
            outro procedimento
        }
        else 
        { 
            mais um procedimento
        }
    }
```

com a simplificação do else if ficaria:

```
if (condicao) 
    { 
         procedimento
    }
    else if (outra condicao) 
    { 
        outro procedimento
    }
    else 
    { 
        mais um procedimento
    }
```

Comment: `else if` é diferente de `elseif` embora ambos tenham o mesmo resultado prático.

Comment: Obrigado, sou iniciante ainda não tenho o conhecimento dessas nuância

Answer (score 5):

No `elseif` é esperado uma condição para executar determinado bloco de código enquanto  `else` é tudo aquilo que não satisfez a condição if. Como por exemplo o calculo de desconto em uma compra onde o cliente ganhar 2% em compras de valor menor ou igual a 100 e caso seja maior 5%.

```
<?php
    $total = 300;
    if($total <= 100){
      $desconto = $total * 0.003;
    }else{
       $desconto = $total * 0.005;
    }
```

Agora caso queira dar diferentes faixas de descontos é necesarios utilizar alguns `elseif`

```
<?php
    $total = 300;
    if($total <= 100){
      $desconto = $total * 0.003;
    }elseif($total > 150 && $total < 300){
       $desconto = $total * 0.005;
    }else{
        $desconto = $total * 0.007;
    }
```

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta!

Answer (score 5):

elseif, é o que o nome sugere, uma combinação do if e do else. Como o else, ele extende um if para executar instruções diferentes no caso do if original retornar FALSE. Entretanto, diferente do else, ele executará uma expressão alternativa somente se a condição do elseif retornar TRUE. Por exemplo, o código a seguir exibirá a is bigger than b, a equal to b ou a is smaller than b:

```
<?php
if ($a > $b) {
    echo "a is bigger than b";
} elseif ($a == $b) {
    echo "a is equal to b";
} else {
    echo "a is smaller than b";
}
?>
```

Pode haver vários elseifs dentro do mesmo if. A primeira expressão elseif (se houver) que retornar TRUE será executado. No PHP, você pode escrever 'else if' (em duas palavras) que o comportamento será idêntico a 'elseif' (em uma única palavra). O significado sintático é um pouco diferente (se você está familiarizado com C, o comportamento é o mesmo) mas no fundo é que ambos terão exatamente o mesmo comportamento.

O elseif só é executado se o if precedente ou qualquer elseif retornar FALSE, e o elseif atual retornar TRUE.

Fonte: http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/control-structures.elseif.php

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta!