# Qual a diferença entre Switch, Case e If, Else?

Tags: php, if, switch

Gostaria de saber qual a diferença entre `switch .. case` e `if .. else`.

Qual oferece um "desempenho" melhor?

Comment: Acho que a minha resposta compara as duas variantes em termos de funcionalidade: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/57792/129; em relação a performance acho que é irrisório. Mas para referência: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3399755/if-versus-switch

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Em suma, a estrutura de controlo  `switch` é um um `if` para operar sobre a mesma variável ou expressão de entrada.

Não existe propriamente uma comparação entre os dois para apurar a sua performance dado o objetivo de cada um ser distinto.

O que existe é o uso correto da estrutura de controlo mais adequada para o nosso objetivo.

## [`switch`](http://ideone.com/qQYySS)

Devemos utilizar quando queremos comparar a mesma variável ou expressão com várias opções:

> A instrução `switch` é similar a uma série de instruções `IF` sobre a mesma expressão. Em muitas ocasiões, você pode querer comparar a mesma variável (ou expressão) com muitos valores diferentes, executando uma peça diferente do código dependendo de qual valor ele se encaixar. Este é exatamente o que a instrução `switch` faz.

Exemplo no [Ideone](http://ideone.com/76YCuQ).

```
switch($a) {
    case 1: {
        echo 'Variável A é igual a 1';
        break;
    }
    case 2: {
        echo 'Variável A é igual a 2';
        break;
    }
    default: {
        echo 'A Variável A não é igual a 1 nem igual a 2';
    }
}
```

<sup>Estamos a comprar `$a` com uma série de valores diferentes.</sup>

## [`if`](http://ideone.com/9RpNku)

Devemos utilizar quando queremos realizar uma série de verificações distintas.

> A construção `if` é uma das características mais importantes de muitas línguas, PHP incluir. Ela permite a execução condicional de fragmentos de código.

Exemplo no [Ideone](http://ideone.com/9RpNku).

```
if ($a > $b) {
    echo "A é maior que B";
}
else if ($a < $b) {
    echo "A é menor que B";
}
else if ($a == $b) {
    echo "A é igual a B";
}
else {
    echo "A é alguma coisa não comparável com B";
}
```

<sup>Estamos a fazer uso de diferentes expressões para executar código em conformidade.</sup>

## Comparação

Para podermos comparar os dois, teríamos que fazer uso de um deles de forma menos adequada:

Usar `switch` de forma menos adequada:

Exemplo no [Ideone](http://ideone.com/qQYySS).

```
switch($a) {
    case ($a > $b): {
        echo "A é maior que B";
        break;
    }
    case ($a < $b): {
        echo "A é menor que B";
        break;
    }
    case ($a == $b): {
        echo "A é igual a B";
        break;
    }
    default: {
        echo "A é alguma coisa não comparável com B";
    }
}

echo PHP_EOL;

switch("batata frita") {
    case ($a > $b): {
        echo "A é maior que B";
        break;
    }
    case ($a < $b): {
        echo "A é menor que B";
        break;
    }
    case ($a == $b): {
        echo "A é igual a B";
        break;
    }
    default: {
        echo "A é alguma coisa não comparável com B";
    }
}
```

<sup>Podemos observar que o valor de entrada não interessa quando fazemos uso do `switch` como se dum `if` se tratasse.</sup>

Usar `if` de forma menos adequada:

Exemplo no [Ideone](http://ideone.com/vB0UG0).

```
if ($a == 1) {
    echo 'Variável A é igual a 1';
}
else if ($a == 2) {
    echo 'Variável A é igual a 2';
}
else {
    echo 'A Variável A não é igual a 1 nem igual a 2';
}
```

<sup>Podemos observar que estamos a comparar a mesma variável com diferentes valores, fazendo uso de uma estrutura de controlo desenha para realizar comparações bem mais complexas do que isto.</sup>

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta, muito bem explicado!

Comment: Apenas para deixar claro e, quem sabe seja interessante adaptar a resposta: o valor de entrada do `switch` interessa e muito. O que acontece que `$a` sendo 1, o PHP trata a entrada como verdadeira e, desta forma, buscará nos `case` a expressão que for verdadeira. Basta inverter os valores de `$a` e `$b` para [ver o que acontece](http://ideone.com/O4FFb3). Sendo `$a` zero, o PHP trata como falso, buscando nos `case` a primeira expressão falsa (`$a > $b`), exibindo um resultado inesperado. O segundo exemplo continua funcionando porque string não vazia é considerada verdadeira pelo PHP.

Answer (score 8):

A comparação deve ser feita na verdade entre `switch` e `if`. O `case` é parte da construção do `switch` para identificar cada bloco. O `else` já tem uma forma semelhante mas funciona de forma diferente.

O `switch` é usado para comparar a igualdade de valores com uma expressão (em geral uma variável é usada). Ele não pode fazer outros tipos de comparação ou relação entre dados. É bem simples, você estabelece uma expressão no `switch` que é um lado da comparação e em cada `case` será colocado uma valor - fixo, tem que ser literal - que será o outro lado da comparação. Ele tentará avaliar todos os valores que estabeleça esta igualdade. Para evitar todas as avaliações seguintes é necessário dizer isto explicitamente no código , provavelmente com `break`.

O `if` avalia qualquer condição, é possível usar expressões complexas estabelecendo comparações e relações que no final resultam em verdadeiro ou falso. Se o resultado for verdadeiro, o bloco de código seguinte será executado, caso contrário será executado o bloco de código estabelecido no `else`. Ainda tem a questão do `elseif` que já foi falado na [outra pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/57791/101). Executando um bloco, ele não avalia a condição e muito menos executa os demais adiante.

A tendência é o `switch` ser ligeiramente mais rápido porque provavelmente ele é implementado com uma [tabela de *lookup*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lookup_table). E a comparação só seria justa de no `if` a expressão também faz uma expressão de igualdade simples. Qualquer outra expressão tornará a comparação sem sentido já que fazem coisas diferentes. Incluindo aí comparar com expressões diferentes. Então você pode comparar a performance destes exemplos:

```
switch ($var) {
    case 0:
        //faz algo
        break;
    case 1:
        //faz algo
        break;
    case 2:
        //faz algo
        break;
    case 3:
        //faz algo
        break;
}
```

E

```
if ($var == 0) {
    //faz algo
} elseif ($var == 1) {
    //faz algo
} elseif ($var == 2) {
    //faz algo
} elseif ($var == 3) {
    //faz algo
}
```

De outras formas, não é possível.

Mesmo que dê alguma diferença, ela será muito pequena, essencialmente insignificante, ainda mais em se tratando de PHP. Não é uma preocupação recomendada, pelo contrário, a opção de um ou outro deve ser pela necessidade. O `switch` ajuda indicar que está procurando por um valor entre uma lista deles. (Não estou com tempo para fazer testes agora mas é certo que eles serão praticamente idênticos).

Desde o PHP 5.5 em alguns casos pode ser mais interessante fazer `['stack', 'overflow'][$x]` do que

```
switch ($x) {
    case 0: 
        echo 'stack';
        break;
    case 1:
        echo 'overflow';
        break;
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/PHP/Syntax/SwitchIfArray.php).

Para PHP a performance é irrelevante.