# Por que esta forma de usar case não funciona?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Tenho o seguinte código:

```
def label_file_type(type)
    label = 
    case type.to_s
    when ['.jpg', '.jpeg', '.png'].include?(type) then
        content_tag(:span, 'Imagem', class: ['label', 'picture'])
    when ['.mp3'].include?(type) then
        content_tag(:span, 'Áudio', class: 'label audio')
    when ['.txt', '.pdf', '.doc', '.docx', '.odt'].include?(type) then
        content_tag(:span, 'Documento', class: 'label document')
    else
        content_tag(:span, 'Indefinido', class: 'label')
    end
end
```

Isto é um helper. Por algum motivo, a única saída que recebo na tela é a do else. É como se a instrução estivesse ignorando todas as comparações e pulando direto pra última. Alguém sabe me explicar o porque de isso não funcionar dessa forma?

Comment: A sintaxe no Ruby é diferente, mas o motivo está explicado aqui: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/58192/qual-a-diferença-entre-switch-case-e-if-else

Answer (score 1):

A sintaxe deveria ser:

```
def label_file_type(type)
    label = 
    case type.to_s
    when '.jpg', '.jpeg', '.png' 
        content_tag(:span, 'Imagem', class: ['label', 'picture'])
    when '.mp3' 
        content_tag(:span, 'Áudio', class: 'label audio')
    when '.txt', '.pdf', '.doc', '.docx', '.odt' 
        content_tag(:span, 'Documento', class: 'label document')
    else
        content_tag(:span, 'Indefinido', class: 'label')
    end
end
```