# O que é uma comparação frouxa?

Tags: php, terminologia, comparação, switch

Na [documentação](http://br.php.net/manual/pt_BR/control-structures.switch.php) do PHP, sobre o `switch` diz:

> **Nota**: Note que o switch/case faz **comparação frouxa**.

O que é uma comparação frouxa? E qual a diferença entre uma comparação frouxa e uma rígida?

Comment: Que pergunta mais saliente ( ͡° ͜ʖ ͡°) (brincadeira, +1)

Comment: Quando você compara o valor e não o tipo de dado. Foi isso que eu entendi dos comentários acima

Comment: Nossa, eu achava que era palavra "trouxa" kkk

Answer (score 25, accepted):

A comparação frouxa é a padrão do PHP. Como uma linguagem de tipagem fraca, ela deixa de lado a rigidez de tipos no momento de comprar, então tenta-se obter um resultado, mesmo que esteja comparando [bananas com maçãs](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/80767/101), o que costuma ser danoso.

Em geral isto é considerado prática ruim e só deveria ser usado se tiver um benefício muito grande, conforme mostra o *link* acima.

A comparação rígida, ou estrita como também é chamada, é feita com `===`, levando em consideração o tipo do dado, portanto se o tipo for diferente, já é garantido que o resultado seja falso. A comparação frouxa usa o `==`. A documentação deixa claro que no momento do `switch` é esta comparação que será usada. Então isto entrará em um `case`

```
$x = "1";
switch ($x) {
    case 1:
        echo "é 1";
        break;
    case 2:
        echo "é 2";
        break;
}
```

[Veja no **ideone**](http://ideone.com/LoSXGS) o efeito provavelmente indesejado de executar algo que deveria ser diferente. E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/lyvimxhh-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/PHP/Syntax/LooseComparison.php).

Em linguagens de tipagem forte nenhum executaria. Em linguagens de tipagem estática nem compilaria.

Note que o `case` é um tipo numérico, mas o valor é um tipo *string*. Quando tenta comparar tipos diferentes ele se perde.

Para evitar que este tipo de problema ocorre, ao contrário do `if` ou outra construção onde você usa explicitamente o `===`, é preciso sanitizar o dado antes de comparar, a não ser que tenha confiança que ele sempre estará certo. Mas quando faz isto na prática não está usando um `switch`, apenas usa a sintaxe dele. O conceito do `switch` é fazer um desvio baseado em uma tabela de dados, não é usar condições. Conceitualmente se vai usar condições, o `if` é mais adequado, principalmente usado a comparação rígida:

```
$x = "1";
if ($x === 1) {
    echo "é 1";
} else if ($x === 2) {
    echo "é 2";
}
```

[Veja no **ideone**](http://ideone.com/KQwOYu) como agora o resultado é mais intuitivo não executando  qualquer dos blocos já que os tipos são diferentes. E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/nnwcgtnq-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/PHP/Syntax/LooseComparison2.php).

Dada essa dificuldade o `switch` do PHP é pouco útil a não ser dos casos que se usa uma grande disciplina no uso das variáveis. Ou se usar o `switch` como se fosse um `if`, o que novamente não tem vantagem. Particularmente não costumo usar. Em geral este mecanismo foi criado em outras linguagens por questão de performance que era melhor que o `if` para estes casos, mas em PHP raramente haverá algum ganho e a sintaxe acaba sendo verbosa e suscetível a erros.

Tem [mais detalhes sobre a escolha do `if` e `switch`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/58192/101). E sobre o novo [`match`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/485419/101).

Na [documentação](http://br.php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php#types.comparisions-loose) há tabelas de como as comparações são feitas. Existe muito mais possibilidade de se obter um verdadeiro com a comparação frouxa, e nem sempre é o desejado.

Answer (score 18):

A comparação **frouxa** não compara o tipo como na comparação **rígida**.

```
$x = 1
$y = "1"
```

`$x` é diferente de `$y` pois apesar de possuírem o mesmo valor, o primeiro é uma variável to tipo `int` e o segundo é do tipo `string`.

A comparação frouxa ignora o tipo e compara apenas o valor. Quando identifica que é um número na string, esse passa a ser tratado como número. Por isso 1 é igual a "1".

Exemplo simples do dia a dia, para quem ficou boiando:

```
$x = 1;
if ($x == true) {

}
```

O exemplo acima retorna verdadeiro pois `true` é igual a `1`. Mas não deveria. Por isso é chamado de *loose comparison* (comparação frouxa).

Quando necessitar de maior consistência nas comparações, utilize *strict comparison* (comparação rídiga):

```
$x = 1;
if ($x === true) {

} else {
    // vai entrar aqui, pois é falso.
}
```

<sub>Note que há um `=` a mais.</sub>

## Comparações rígidas com *switch case*

Por padrão o switch case não faz comparação rígida mas é possível contornar. Exemplo:

```
$x = 1;
switch (true) {
    case ($x === "1"):

        break;
}
```

## Tabela de comparações

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[Documentação do PHP](http://br.php.net/manual/pt_BR/types.comparisons.php#types.comparisions-loose)

## Caso de estudo

Um exemplo de como é importante saber quando usar, veja essa comparação um tanto "perigosa" com `md5()`:

```
var_dump(md5('240610708') == md5('QNKCDZO'));
```

`0e462097431906509019562988736854` é diferente de `0e830400451993494058024219903391`, não?

Veja a diferença:

```
var_dump('0e462097431906509019562988736854' == '0e830400451993494058024219903391');

var_dump('0e462097431906509019562988736854' === '0e830400451993494058024219903391');
```