# Função de validação recebe número 0 ou 1

Tags: php

Fiz uma função de validação para aceitar somente 1 ou 0, porém tanto 1 ou 0 estão sendo interpretados como INVÁLIDOS. Alguma sugestão sobre qual seria o erro?

```
function valida_variavel_zero_um($valor){
     if((empty($valor)) OR (strlen($valor) != 1)
      OR ($valor !=1 || $valor !=0)){
        return "INVALIDO";
     }else{
        return $valor;
     }

}
```

Comment: Se for 0, a condição `$valor != 1` é verdadeira e entra no `if`. Se for 1, a condição `$valor != 0` é verdadeira e entra no `if`. Consegue entender o problema?

Comment: Então eu teria que trabalhar com $valor != "1" dessa forma?

Comment: não sei de onde esta vindo a variavel $valor, mais verifica se ela é realmente um int, da um parseInt, antes do if, repense seu if, esta redundante, qualquer uma das operações que der true ele entrara no if, por exemplo o 'empty($valor)', se ela tiver valor, cairá dentro do if

Comment: Entendi. Estou passando o $valor de forma direta mesmo. só quero criar uma função de validação para o campo não ser vazio, e só aceitar 1 ou 0. Para quando outros usuários forem utilizar a aplicação der algum erro se algum desses requisitos não forem atendidos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O erro está na sua condição.

1. Ao utilizar o `empty`, que pode gerar resultados inesperados, pois `empty(false)` retorna verdadeiro, entrando no `if`, mas `empty(true)` retorna falso;
2. Ao utilizar `strlen != 1`, pois também está suscetível a resultados inesperados, visto que `strlen(false)` retorna 0, que é diferente de 1, entrando no `if`, mas `strlen(true)` retorna 1;
3. Na parte `($valor !=1 || $valor !=0)`, pois se `$valor` for igual a 0, a condição `$valor != 1` será verdadeira, fazendo com que o programa entre no `if` e retorne inválido; o mesmo acontece quando `$valor` for igual a 1, pois a condição `$valor != 0` passa a ser verdadeira, também entrando no `if`. A correção do problema resume-se em mudar o operador `||` para `&&`;

Para mostrar quão estranho poderiam ser os resultados, basta fazer o teste:

```
function valida_variavel_zero_um($valor){
     if((empty($valor)) OR (strlen($valor) != 1) OR ($valor != 1 && $valor != 0)){
        return "INVALIDO";
     }else{
        return $valor;
     }
}

$tests = [0, 1, false, true, "0", "1", [], "", 0.0, -0.0, 1.0];

foreach ($tests as $test)
{
    var_dump( valida_variavel_zero_um($test) );
}
```

<sup>Veja funcionando no [Ideone](https://ideone.com/UPWUw3) | [Repl.it](https://repl.it/NTSW/0)</sup>

Obtendo o resultado:

```
string(8) "INVALIDO"    // $valor = 0
int(1)                  // $valor = 1
string(8) "INVALIDO"    // $valor = false
bool(true)              // $valor = true
string(8) "INVALIDO"    // $valor = "0"
string(1) "1"           // $valor = "1"
string(8) "INVALIDO"    // $valor = []
string(8) "INVALIDO"    // $valor = ""
string(8) "INVALIDO"    // $valor = 0.0
string(8) "INVALIDO"    // $valor = -0.0
float(1)                // $valor = 1.0
```

Percebe quão estranhos são esses resultados? Alguns pares de valores semelhantes produzem resultados diferentes: 0 é inválido, mas 1 é válido; `false` é inválido, mas `true` é válido; 0.0 é inválido, mas 1.0 é válido.

Não faz muito sentido, então proponho outra solução:

**Solução 1**

A solução que eu proponho tem uma condição bem simples:

```
function valida_variavel_zero_um($valor)
{
    if ($valor !== 0 && $valor !== 1)
    {
        return "inválido";
    }

    return $valor;
}
```

Ao utilizar o operador `!==`, você verificará tanto o valor quanto o tipo. Ao fazer alguns testes breves:

```
$tests = [0, 1, false, true, "0", "1", [], "", 0.0, -0.0, 1.0];

foreach ($tests as $test)
{
    var_dump( valida_variavel_zero_um($test) );
}
```

Teremos a saída:

```
int(0)                  // $valor = 0
int(1)                  // $valor = 1
string(9) "inválido"    // $valor = false
string(9) "inválido"    // $valor = true
string(9) "inválido"    // $valor = "0"
string(9) "inválido"    // $valor = "1"
string(9) "inválido"    // $valor = []
string(9) "inválido"    // $valor = ""
string(9) "inválido"    // $valor = 0.0
string(9) "inválido"    // $valor = -0.0
string(9) "inválido"    // $valor = 1.0
```

<sup>Veja funcionando no [Ideone](https://ideone.com/kJsOEC) | [Repl.it](https://repl.it/NTNp/0)</sup>

**Solução 2**

Outra forma de implementar a função seria explicitar o tipo definindo-o na lista de argumentos da função:

```
function valida_variavel_zero_um(int $valor)
{
    if ($valor != 0 && $valor != 1)
    {
        return "inválido";
    }

    return $valor;
}
```

<sup>Veja funcionando no [Ideone](https://ideone.com/BSg4nI) | [Repl.it](https://repl.it/NTO7/0)</sup>

Porém, ao chamar a função com valores não inteiros, o PHP tentará convertê-los para o tipo `int` antes de passá-los como parâmetro. Isto é, chamar a função `valida_variavel_zero_um(false)` retornaria 0 e `valida_variavel_zero_um(true)` retornaria 1, pois `false` e `true`, quando analisados como inteiros, são 0 e 1 respectivamente. Isso pode gerar problemas na aplicação caso esse retorno não seja esperado para esses parâmetros.

A saída dos testes para esta solução é:

```
int(0)   // $valor = 0
int(1)   // $valor = 1
int(0)   // $valor = false
int(1)   // $valor = true
int(0)   // $valor = "0"
int(1)   // $valor = "1"
Argument 1 passed to valida_variavel_zero_um() must be of the type integer, array given, called in /home/tzgjpG/prog.php on line 18
Argument 1 passed to valida_variavel_zero_um() must be of the type integer, string given, called in /home/tzgjpG/prog.php on line 18
int(0)   // $valor = 0.0
int(0)   // $valor = -0.0
int(1)   // $valor = 1.0
```

**Solução 3**

Outra forma, citada inclusive pelo Victor nos comentários, seria tentar analisar o valor do parâmetro com a função `intval`, porém, o problema da solução 2 persiste nesta solução, pois a mesma conversão de tipos que o PHP faz implicitamente quando é definido o tipo na lista de parâmetros ele fará com a função `intval`:

```
function valida_variavel_zero_um($valor)
{
    $valor = intval($valor);

    if ($valor != 0 && $valor != 1)
    {
        return "inválido";
    }

    return $valor;
}
```

<sup>Veja funcionando no [Ideone](https://ideone.com/avVeVl) | [Repl.it](https://repl.it/NTPK/0)</sup>

O resultado dos testes para esta solução é:

```
int(0)   // $valor = 0
int(1)   // $valor = 1
int(0)   // $valor = false
int(1)   // $valor = true
int(0)   // $valor = "0"
int(1)   // $valor = "1"
int(0)   // $valor = []
int(0)   // $valor = ""
int(0)   // $valor = 0.0
int(0)   // $valor = -0.0
int(1)   // $valor = 1.0
```

Ou seja, mesma passando booleanos, *strings*, *arrays* e números com ponto flutuante como parâmetro, a função sempre retornará um valor válido conforme o valor passado. Novamente, esta solução pode trazer problemas para aplicação por trazer resultados possivelmente inesperados.

As três soluções são válidas e dependerá somente da sua necessidade. Por questões de semântica, eu prefiro a solução 1, que só retorna valores válidos quando a entrada é 0 ou 1, inteiros, que aparentemente é o que se pede na pergunta.

**Leitura obrigatória**

[O que é uma comparação frouxa?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/215652/5878)

Answer (score 1):

Como já dito na outra resposta, o uso da `if` esta se confundindo nos ORs:

```
if((empty($valor)) OR (strlen($valor) != 1)
  OR ($valor !=1 || $valor !=0)){
```

Creio eu que se os valores aceitos apenas são `0` e `1` você pode usar uma checagem mais **estrita** que além de tornar o código mais simples ainda vai evitar certas redundâncias de checagem.

Os operadores `===` e `!==` diferente dos `!=` e `==` fazem checagem tanto do "valor" quanto do "tipo" em PHP, mais detalhes em [**Comparison Operators**](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php)

Então se os valores aceitos são apenas 0 e 1, sendo `integer` ou `string` você pode simplificar facilmente assim:

```
function valida_variavel_zero_um($valor)
{
    if ($valor === 0 || $valor === "0" || $valor === 1 || $valor === "1") {
        return $valor;
    }

    return "INVALIDO";
}
```

<sub>Exemplo no [jsfiddle](https://ideone.com/Bhwsec)</sub>

Existe também uma função chamada [**`in_array`**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) que suporta checagem estrita também:

```
bool in_array ( mixed $needle , array $haystack [, bool $strict = FALSE ] )
```

O que pode facilitar em muito para escrever a `if`, ficando assim:

```
function valida_variavel_zero_um($valor)
{
    if (in_array($valor, array(0, 1, '0', '1'), true)) {
        return $valor;
    }

    return "INVALIDO";
}
```

<sub>Exemplo no [jsfiddle](https://ideone.com/548GMH)</sub>

---

### Valores `float`

Mas é claro que as sugestões é se não houver valores possivelmente quebrados, se existir essa possibilidade em seu código pessoalmente acho a [**Solução 3**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/250069/3635) do Anderson a mais ideal, agora se não existir a possibilidade de haver valores do tipo `float` creio que checagem estrita resolverá tudo sem problemas