# Condição para aparecer link não funciona

Tags: php, html

Tenho a seguinte logica que dependendo  do que o usuário digitar, irá retornar um link, entretanto não funciona.

```
<nav id="menu">
<ul>
    <li><a href="index.php">Minimo Nulo</a></li>
    <li><a href="Fechamento.php">Divergência de campos </a></li>

    <?php

    if($nivel != "MM" || $nivel != "AAAA"){

      $function = '';

    } else {

    $function = '<li>''<a href="Alt_Papel.php">' . Alterar papel - D . '</a>''</li>';

    }

    echo $function;

    ?>
</ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primeiramente, eu recomendaria utilizar o operador de idêntico no PHP para comparar strings que no caso seria o `!==` ao invês de somente `!=` ou então utilizar o `strcmp()` para tal feito.

Outra coisa é dizer que a segunda atribuição para o valor string da variável `$function` está com problemas, você não deve concatenar a string desta forma.

Mais um adendo seria utilizar um operador de if ternário para realizar tal condição imposta por você, sem a necessidade da criação de uma variável também.

Nesta parte você deveria utilizar um `.` para delimitar uma string de outra, ou então tornar a string como um só.

```
$function = '<li>''<a href="Alt_Papel.php">'.Alterar papel - D.'</a>''</li>'; //isto é totalmente incorreto.
$function = '<li>'.'<a href="Alt_Papel.php">'.'Alterar papel - D'.'</a>'.'</li>'; //isto é correto, porém não necessário.
$function = '<li><a href="Alt_Papel.php">Alterar papel - D</a></li>'; //isto é ideal.
```

Somente para exemplo, pois há também outra parte incorreta na sua string.

Aplicando as recomendações que eu mencionei seu código ficaria desta forma:

```html
<nav id="menu">
<ul>
    <li><a href="index.php">Minimo Nulo</a></li>
    <li><a href="Fechamento.php">Divergência de campos </a></li>

    <?php
    echo ($nivel !== 'MM' || $nivel !== 'AAAA') ? '' : '<li><a href="Alt_Papel.php"> Alterar papel - D </a></li>';
    ?>
</ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Valeu cara, eu tô começando com PHP tô dando umas vaciladas em algumas coisas que não entendo muito ainda, mas muito obrigado pelas dicas e pela resposta

Comment: Boa sorte nesta jornada, PHP é algo meio rústico e problemático eu diria ^^ hehe

Comment: Relacionado: [O que é um operador condicional](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/56831/57801)

Comment: Relacionado: [O que é uma comparação frouxa?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/215659/57801)

Comment: @PauloRoberto Sim eu percebi kkk, a maioria das soluções que arranjeipara os problemas que tive foram "gambiarras".

Comment: Mas tenha em mente. Gambiarra é questão de ponto de vista, na maioria das vezes sempre existirá uma maneira melhor de fazer algo que você está fazendo. Só procure se limitar ao que a linguagem tem definida como limites, e não somente se limitar ao que teu conhecimento permite.

Answer (score 1):

Você está concatenando aonde não necessita concatenar, o certo seria...

```
$function = '<li><a href="Alt_Papel.php"> Alterar papel - D </a></li>';
```

Comment: Essa publicação está caindo em "baixa qualidade" devido ao tamanho do seu conteúdo. Por favor, exemplifique melhor sua resposta. [Revisao](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/146519)