# Problema com $_POST e IF

Tags: php, if

Estou tentando fazer q se caso a pessoa digite 12 em qualquer parte do texto ele entre no if mas ele n esta entrando

```
if ($_POST['mensagem'] !="%12%"){
        echo"vc digitou 12";
    }
```

Comment: Esta sintaxe que utilizou não existe. Pesquise por `strpos`.

Comment: Além do citado acima, como eu digitei 12 se a comparação é de diferença??

Comment: coloquei errado essa parte era vc n digitou 12 kkkk

Comment: obg @AndersonCarlosWoss vou procurar

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Para saber se um texto está contido em outro se usa `strpos`.

```
if ( strpos( $_POST['mensagem'] , '12' ) !== false ){
    echo 'vc digitou 12';
}
```

**Importante:** note o uso de `!== false`, pois se a *string* estiver no começo, usar apenas `!=` vai dar errado, pois o resultado do `strpos` será zero, indicando que há um `12`, mas no começo da `string`, pois a contagem se inicia na posição zero.

Se quiser o comportamento inverso:

```
if ( strpos( $_POST['mensagem'] , '12' ) === false ){
    echo 'vc NAO digitou 12';
}
```

Use `===` pela mesma razão explicada anteriormente.

Perceba que há outras funçoes para encontrar *substrings*, mas o próprio manual recomenda a `strpos` para estes casos, pela diferença significativa de performance.

Mais detalhes no manual:

> https://secure.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.strpos.php

Leitura recomendada sobre a diferença de `===` e `!==` para `==` e `!=`:

> [O que é uma comparação frouxa?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/215652/70)

Comment: Não entendi o voto negativo