# Duas condições diferentes são válidas para um mesmo valor

Tags: php

```
<td>
   <? if($online['status']==1){?>
    <span class="badge badge-primary"><?php echo lang('texto um'); ?></span>
   <?}else{?>

   <? }?>

   <?if($online['status']==2){?>
     <span class="badge badge-danger"><?php echo lang('texto dois'); ?></span>
   <? }else{?>

   <? }?>
   ...
</td>
```

Na tabela está imprimindo os dois, mas era para imprimir conforme o status na tabela.

O que está errado?

Comment: E qual é o valor de `$online['status']`? Tome cuidado com a [comparação frouxa](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/215652/5878), ela pode te enganar em muitas situações.

Comment: Varia de 1 e 4 . Sempre imprime os quatros textos em vez de apenas o texto correspondente ao status

Comment: Verificou se o valor está chegando certo? Dê um `var_dump($online)` e poste o resultado.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Tenta fazer assim. Sempre quando houver uma condição nova no "if" utilize o "elseif":

```
<td>
    <?php
       if($online['status'] === 1){
    ?>
      <span class="badge badge-primary"><?php echo lang('texto um'); ?></span>
    <?php
      }elseif($online['status'] === 2){
    ?>
      <span class="badge badge-danger"><?php echo lang('texto dois'); ?></span>
    <?php
      }else{
    ?>
      etc etc etc etc continua
    <?php
     }
    ?>
</td>
```

Comment: Acho interessante você explicar o porquê mudou de `==` para `===`, pois é fundamental para entender a sua resposta.