# Manipulação de JSON com PHP

Tags: php, json

Tenho esse código `PHP` que esta manipulando o `JSON` criado no inicio, no final ele vai ***imprimir/listar*** um `foreach` com todos os dados.

Minha dúvida é a seguinte, eu não quero imprimir todas as 3 linhas, quero imprimir só a segunda linha do meu `JSON` por exemplo.

Como eu poderia fazer isso?

```
<?php

$json_str = '{"empregados": '. 
        '[{"nome":"Jason Jones", "idade":38, "sexo": "M"},'.
        '{"nome":"Ada Pascalina", "idade":35, "sexo": "F"},'.
        '{"nome":"Delphino da Silva", "idade":26, "sexo": "M"}'.
        ']}';

$jsonObj = json_decode($json_str);
$empregados = $jsonObj->empregados;

foreach ( $empregados as $e )
{
    echo "nome: $e->nome - idade: $e->idade - sexo: $e->sexo<br>"; 
}
?>
```

Comment: imprimir somente a linha 2 (`$empregados[1]`) porque o `array` em PHP tem o seu inicio pelo **0** sendo essa a posição **1** e assim por diante.

Comment: `$empregados` é um array, então para acessar a segunda linha basta fazer `$empregados[1]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No seu caso `$empregados` será um *array*, então basta acessar a segunda posição dele, não tem mistérios.

```
$empregados = $jsonObj->empregados;
$segundoEmpregado = $empregados[1];

echo $segundoEmpregado->nome;
```

Simples assim. Como você sabe a posição, basta acessá-la diretamente, pois isso será uma operação O(1), dado que o *array* no PHP, mesmo com índices numéricos, é implementado na forma de um mapa, relacionando chave/valor. Assim, não haverá custos na aplicação para buscar dentro do *array* o valor desejado.

Foi sugerido em outra resposta fazer um laço com uma verificação:

```
foreach($empregados as $key => $empregado){
    if($key == 1){
        //ação somente para o índice 1 (que é o segundo elemento do array)
    }
}
```

Isso produz o resultado esperado, mas é desnecessário para esse problema. Esta solução percorrerá sempre o *array* inteiro, o que não justifica se você precisar apenas de uma posição. A busca será O(n) e se o *array* for muito grande isso trará prejuízos na performance da sua aplicação.

Essa solução talvez será útil quando você precisar de múltiplos valores, que fazem a busca O(n) ser viável. Buscar por exemplo uma lista grande de posições que é gerada dinamicamente:

```
foreach($empregados as $key => $empregado){
    if(in_array($key, $posicoes)){
        // ...
    }
}
```

Em todos os casos, é sempre bom alertar sobre utilizar a [comparação frouxa](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/215652/5878), pois pode gerar efeitos colaterais difíceis de identificar na manutenção.