# Quais são as diferenças entre match e switch no PHP8?

Tags: php, característica-linguagem, php-8, pattern-matching

O PHP 8 parece [já ter sido lançado](https://www.php.net/ChangeLog-8.php#8.0.0), com uma série de mudanças e coisas novas. Entre as mudanças, criaram a expressão [match](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/control-structures.match.php).

Vi que ela lembra um pouco o velho e tradicional `switch`, mas parece um pouco diferente.

Exemplo da documentação:

```
$age = 23;

$result = match (true) {
    $age >= 65 => 'senior',
    $age >= 25 => 'adult',
    $age >= 18 => 'young adult',
    default => 'kid',
};

var_dump($result); // string(11) "young adult"
```

Gostaria de saber:

- Quais são as principais diferenças entre `switch` e `match`?
- Essa funcionalidade substitui `switch` ou é apenas diferente?

Comment: A finalidade do switch não é retornar resultados, e sim controlar fluxo. Nas linguagens onde é implementado corretamente, o switch equivale ao `goto`, criando efetivamente uma jumplist (e não ao `if` / `elseif`, como os leigos confundem) - No PHP sempre foi uma coisa nebulosa. O `match` provavelmente corresponde à atual tendência da linguagem de "ah, essa outra linguagem tem, então também precisamos", o que na prática só é mais uma expressão qualquer. Seja lá como usarem, já tinha como fazer a mesma coisa antes, mas vai agradar quem acredita na lenda de que "escrever menos é sempre melhor".

Comment: Interessante seria mostrar que não é uma ideia nova mas que é algo já existente a muito em linguagens funcionais e agora importado para o PHP, [Pattern match](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pattern_matching).

Comment: Realmente, @AugustoVasques, e o pior é que o PHP implementou de uma forma "pobre", sem fazer uso de todo o poder que a _ideia_ do _pattern match_ traz. Veja como é mais poderoso em linguagens como [Rust](https://doc.rust-lang.org/rust-by-example/flow_control/match.html), Haskell, Elixir ou até a [proposta que pode vir para o JavaScript](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-pattern-matching), pois permite, por exemplo, "desempacotar" valores de tipos algébricos mais complexos (como tuplas, _records_ etc). Aparentemente o PHP (ainda?) não permite isso.

Comment: Quanto a funcionalidade, se parece mais com o vários condicionais ternários (`c ? t : f`) encadeados

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## A declaração `switch`

Basicamente, o `switch` é um **declaração** (no inglês *statement*) que permite o programador controlar o fluxo do código. O `switch` decide quais "braços" serão executados com base em uma sequência de comparações.

O `switch` recebe um valor principal, ao qual será comparado pelo valor colocado em cada `case`. Em todos os casos em que a comparação de igualdade for verdadeira, corpo do `case` será executado.

Um exemplo:

```
<?php
$a = 5;
$b = 6;
$operator = '*';

switch ($operator) {
    case '+':
        echo 'Soma: ' . $a + $b;
        break;
    case '-':
        echo 'Subtração: ' . $a - $b;
        break;
    case '*':
        echo 'Multiplicação: ' . $a * $b;
        break;
    case '/':
        // Cuidado com a divisão por zero.
        echo 'Divisão: ' . $a / $b;
        break;
    default:
        echo 'Operação inválida.';
}
```

Observe que:

- O `switch` foi utilizado para alterar o fluxo do código, a depender da variável `$operator`.
- Utilizei o `break` ao final de cada `case` (exceto no `default`). Isso é necessário porque, sem eles, o `switch` executaria *todos* os cases abaixo daquele que foi avaliado verdadeiramente. Esse comportamento é chamado *switch fallthrough*.

Pode-se afirmar, portanto, que o principal objetivo de um `switch` é controlar o fluxo de um código através da comparação da igualdade entre o valor do `switch` ao de cada `case`.

Eventualmente, para substituir uma sequência de vários `if`/`else`s pela declaração `switch`, alguns programadores utilizam `switch (true)` como artifício para fazer com que cada `case` seja executado a partir de uma avaliação de valor verdadeiro (já que cada `case` será implicitamente comparado com `true`, a expressão passada para o `switch`). No entanto, essa prática pode ser classificada como "gambiarra", uma vez que utiliza do `switch` para fazer algo que uma sequência de `if`/`else` faz — a economia de linhas é, também, raramente significante ao ponto de justificar tal utilização.

---

## A expressão `match`

Ao contrário do `switch`, o `match` é uma **expressão** e, por isso, sempre deve retornar um valor. Por isso, o uso de `match` será agora recomendado quando tiver que se retornar um valor.

Vejamos um outro exemplo de `switch`, que utiliza de uma variável externa para armazenar o valor computado:

```
<?php
$a = 5;
$b = 6;
$operator = '*';

$result = 0; // Armazenaremos o resultado das computações aqui.
switch ($operator) {
    case '+': $result = $a + $b; break;
    case '-': $result = $a - $b; break;
    case '*': $result = $a * $b; break;
    case '/': $result = $a / $b; break;
}

echo "O resultado da operação com o operador `$operator` é $result.";
```

Note que, como `switch` foi feito para *controlar fluxo*, se quisermos utilizá-lo para computar um valor, temos que manter uma variável **externa**. Fiz isso com `$result`, para armazenar o resultado obtido pela "calculadora" implementada.

Nesse tipo de cenário, o `switch` pode ser elegantemente substituído por uma expressão `match`:

```
<?php
$a = 5;
$b = 6;
$operator = '*';

$result = match ($operator) {
    '+' => $a + $b,
    '-' => $a - $b,
    '*' => $a * $b,
    '/' => $a / $b
};

echo "O resultado da operação com o operador `$operator` é $result.";
```

A saída do código é a mesma, mas a diferença é gritante. Note que, como `match` é uma expressão, ao contrário do `switch`, o uso de ponto e vírgula ao final da expressão é obrigatório.

Observe também que, embora o `switch` permita a utilização de um *default case*, ele acaba sendo opcional (como fiz nos exemplo acima). No `match`, no entanto, embora você tenha a opção de utilizar um *default case*, no caso de você não o incluir, uma exceção do tipo `UnhandledMatchError` será lançada se uma expressão sem *match* for encontrada. Isso mostra que `match` sempre há de retornar um valor. Caso contrário, você deverá lidar com essa exceção. [Mais detalhes na documentação.](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.match.php#example-135)

## Diferenças

De modo geral, as diferenças são:

- O `switch` é uma declaração e `match` é uma expressão. Portanto, `switch` por si só não é capaz de produzir um valor ao ser avaliado. Já `match`, sim.
- Ausência de coerção de tipos. Ao comparar os valores de cada `case`, `switch` utiliza o operador `==` (que faz conversão automática de tipos). Já o `match`, ao fazer as avaliações, utiliza `===` (que não faz coerção de tipos).
- O `switch` permite que vários `case`s sejam executados em seguida (se você não utilizar o `break`). Isso se chama *fallthrough*. Ao contrário, `match` não permite isso, permitindo que somente um braço seja avaliado por vez.
- O `match` é exaustivo. Isso é, se encontrar uma condição que não cabe a nenhum dos braços, a exceção `UnhandledMatchError`. O `switch` não possui algo do tipo e permite que nem todos os possíveis casos sejam lidados (geralmente isso ocorre por falha do programador).

A [página do RFC](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/match_expression_v2) detalha cada uma dessas diferenças. Consulte-a para mais detalhes.

É bem mais poderoso que um `switch`. Também ajuda, de certo modo, programadores mais desatentos, já que possui "mecanismos nativos de defesa". No entanto, não consegui encontrar um caso de uso que o `switch` não desse conta — acaba que `switch` (quando utilizado para produzir valor) é um pouco mais verboso, mas isso raramente é um problema.

Agora pode-se dizer que é mais correto utilizar `switch` unicamente para controlar fluxo. Na possibilidade do controle de fluxo ter que gerar um valor, `match` provavelmente será o mais adequado.

Basicamente, a programação funcional tem ascendido popularidade recentemente e *pattern matching* é um recurso muito comum entre linguagens funcionais. Assim, o PHP, provavelmente para não "ficar para trás", parece ter decidido *copiar* esses recursos. Há quem diga que é bom, pois moderniza a linguagem. Outros podem achar que não. De certo modo, ambos os lados têm razão. Introduzir esse tipo de recurso pode facilitar certos casos de uso, mas será que realmente vale a pena introduzir um novo tipo de construção sintática na linguagem?

Comment: Eu não sei, mas, eu acho que a rede é muito preconceituosa com PHP e também quem desenvolve com PHP, quando há recursos adicionados sempre tem pessoas criticando que isso não é bom, que isso não faz sentido, que escrever menos nem sempre é o melhor, mas, a galera que realmente gosta do PHP e utiliza gostou muito das últimas novidades, só queria deixar ratificado isso, porque eu vejo aqui não de maneira geral criticas muitos infundadas. Gostei da sua resposta +1.

Comment: @novic, obrigado. :) Não diria que é preconceito, mas sim _talvez_ (não posso falar por ninguém) preocupação. De modo geral, entendo que quem gostou da adição (eu mesmo espero pela [introdução de algo parecido no JS](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-pattern-matching)) pode utilizar o novo recurso para fazer códigos mais expressivos e curtos. No entanto, pelo menos até onde pude constatar, o _pattern matching_ do PHP é um pouco limitado, o q pode também não justificar sua adição. Não consegui ver nenhum exemplo de _match_ para estruturas aninhadas (veja último exemplo no link anterior) em PHP.

Comment: Talvez seja possível e só não tenha sido documentado, mas ainda não tive tempo de testar. Se for possível, atualizarei esta resposta. Mas estou confiante de que, pelo menos atualmente, o `match` do PHP (infelizmente) só pode ser utilizado nesse tipo de avaliação mais simples.

Comment: A comunidade PHP que eu participo, porque eu programo desde a versão 3 gostou muito eu ainda não utilize a versão 8 porque ainda é novo e tudo que é novo precisa de um tempo para possamos entender. Um recurso do `Typescript` na declaração no construtor de propriedades eu por exemplo achei interessante e útil. Eu ainda não acho que é preocupação, porque, imagina você é só não utilizar no seu código o novo recurso.

Comment: @LuizFelipe exato, o problema maior é que foi feita uma funcionalidade meia-boca, sem resolver os problemas originais do `switch`, e que não introduz nada importante na linguagem. O problema maior é que como grande parte dos usuários da linguagem não tem compromisso com o certo, aplaude qualquer coisa. O maior problema do PHP é o descompromisso de parte dos usuários, e não a linguagem em si (tem cara que usa faz não sei quantos anos e não sai da mesma mentalidade, é de chorar). Só que graças a isso, a linguagem foi perdendo o que a deixava vantajosa, e está tentando virar outra coisa.

Comment: Agora, nem adianta eu querer prolongar muito isso nos comentários, pois o tempo que tenho usando PHP é maior do que a idade de grande maioria dos usuários do site, então pra conseguir situar todo mundo, este espaço aqui não seria adequado (e nem é minha função), então, cada  um que use como quer, fazer o que. Só acho uma pena, pelo potencial desperdiçado. Ainda mais que uso PHP profissionalmente, entre outras linguagens, então não é questão só de gosto, tem o aspecto prático, e preocupação legítima.

Comment: Aqui por exemplo a comunidade Laravel fugiu, por causa de manifestações contrárias e que só atacam a grande maioria dos desenvolvedores, o julgamento é um forma trivial na rede e talvez isso é um fator onde um sabe tudo e os outros não sabem nada. Vale muito lembrar que sempre teve isso com PHP a desmoralização das pessoas e da própria linguagem.

Comment: Eu vejo no geral as pessoas que entendem de computação, de linguagens de programação, criticarem tudo  o que é ruim de PHP, JS, Python e Java, C#, C++, e quaisquer outras linguagem que as pessoas usam e que seja um erro conceitual fazer aquilo, ou pelo menos seja de mau gosto. Não espero o mesmo nível de crítica entre os que não entendem de fato como os mecanismos devem se comportar. E não espero da comunidade PHP criticar algo que a linguagem faça errado. não só por esse motivo já falado, mas também porque com a quantidade grande seria admissão de ser masoquista.

Answer (score 0):

As diferenças: O `match` é uma expressão mais curta, que não precisa usar `break` em sua estrutura, você não precisa necessariamente declarar variáveis para cada caso, para retornar algo, apenas dizer diretamente o que ele irá retornar, ele pode combinar diferentes expressões usando virgula, ele é No type coercion, ou seja, é como se ele usasse `===` ao invés de `==`, Exemplo:

```
$message = match ($statuscode) {
   200, 301 => null,
   404 => 'not found',
   500 => 'ERROR',
   default => 'unknown status code',
};
```

Valores desconhecidos irão lançar erros:

```
$statuscode = 1000000
$retorno = match($stauscode){
   500000 => 'Meio Milhão',
};
```

Nesse caso irá retornar `UnhandledMatchError`

Você pode ver mais detalhes e especificidades sobre match em: https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/control-structures.match.php

Já o `switch` é bem mais flexível, principalmente a nível de comparação, ele faz uma serie de comparações para decidir quais trechos de códigos, 'arms', serão executados, nele você tem que usar `break`, para que quando uma condição for atendida a execução do switch pare. Exemplo:

```
switch (true) {
case ($a === true):
    echo '$a is true';
    break;
case ($a === false):
    echo '$a is false';
    break;
case ($a === 0):
    echo '$a is 0';
    break;
}
```

Você pode ver mais sobre switch, na documentação do PHP: https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/control-structures.switch.php