# Condição IF - Boa prática de utilização

Tags: if, condição

Durante uma codificação tive que realizar o desenvolvimento da seguinte maneira:

```
IF (Condicao1 = True)
  IF (Condicao2 = True)
    IF (Condicao3 = True)
       Imprime(Mensagem);
```

A maneira que realizei é considerado a melhor prática?

Existiria uma maneira melhor de realizar isto?

Comment: Relacionada(ou duplicata):[Por que em algumas situações if's são considerados ruins?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/4731/por-que-em-algumas-situa%C3%A7%C3%B5es-ifs-s%C3%A3o-considerados-ruins)

Comment: Relacionado: [Qual a diferença entre Switch, Case e If, Else?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/58192/qual-a-diferen%C3%A7a-entre-switch-case-e-if-else)

Comment: Conhece o operador lógico *and*? `If (condicao1 and condicao2 and condicao3) Imprime(Mensagem)`

Comment: Não sei se usar and é o mais recomendavel. Pode ter casos em que não se deseja validar uma igualdade de todas as condições de forma unica. Acredito que o switch possa ser a solução quando se quer validar condição por condição, ou o OR, dependendo do caso.

Comment: É interessante você especificar qual a linguagem você utiliza. Algumas linguagens tratam operadores relacionais `AND/OR` em modo de `short-circuit` e dessa forma um `AND` pode funcionar como vários `IF` encadeados, mas outras linguagens não usam esse modo.

Answer (score 2):

Aparentemente a forma que você estruturou não é a melhor. Digo isso porque você não utiliza *chaves* nos *ifs*, o que sugere que sejam apenas para o que está sendo exibido no código, ou seja, validar se as três condições são verdade; sendo, *imprime*. Assim, a melhor alternativa é utilizar o *and* , como já dito em um comentário:

```
IF (Condicao1 && Condicao2 && Condicao3)
    Imprime(Mensagem);
```

Porém, se existirem comandos a serem executados no caso de algumas delas ser falsa, você estruturou da maneira correta.

```
IF (Condicao1 = True) {
  IF (Condicao2 = True){
    IF (Condicao3 = True){
       Imprime(Mensagem);
    } else {
      // codigo
    }
  } else {
    //codigo
  }
} else {
  //código
}
```

Caso não precise de algum dos *"senões"*, use a primeira forma.