# Condições não retornam valores esperados

Tags: php, post

Possuo uma aplicação em HTML e php simples, que consiste em 2 campos, aonde eles serão recebidos em uma pagina php pelo método `$_POST`. Se eu adicionar os valores ao campo, vai corretamente. Porem se eu não adicionar nada, eu esperava que caísse em "Não houve submit", mas ele sempre me joga para "Preencha os campos".

Acredito que seja um problema nos `else` porem não consegui encontrar onde.

```
<?php

     if (!empty($_POST)) {
         if ((isset($_POST['nome'])) && (isset($_POST['qtde']))) {
             if ((!empty($_POST['nome'])) && (!empty($_POST['qtde']))) {
                 $nome = $_POST['nome'];
                 $qtde = $_POST['qtde'];
                 echo "Aviso ao representate $nome <br/>
         A equipe com $qtde alunos foi aceita!";

             } else echo "Preencha os campos";

         } else echo "O campo [nome] nao existe na variavel $_POST";


     }else
         echo "não houve submit";





?>
```

Comment: Aparentimenta está correto, pois se você não preencher os campos e enviar, ainda sim será uma requisição, onde a variável $_POST não estará vazia e só os campos nome e qtde dentro dela que estaram.

Comment: Acho que você está certo Yure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Demorei um pouco pra acabar a resposta, e ainda não olhei as outras. Fiz mais porque pra mim representou um "desafio alcançável", e mesmo sabendo que tem gente bem melhor que eu pra responder, vou me arriscar nessa. :)

Bom, a primeira coisa é entender o que significa cada condição no seu código.

```
if (!empty($_POST)) {
//outras condições
}
else {
 echo "Não houve submit.";
}
```

Esta primeira condição quer dizer o seguinte:

> Se a variável global `$_POST` **não estiver vazia**, verifique as outras condições abaixo. Se ela **estiver vazia**, escreva: "Não houve submit".

Então, a única forma de você receber a resposta "Não houve submit", é se a variável `$_POST` não contiver nada dentro dela, e quando você envia as informações através do botão `submit`, a variável $_POST irá conter as informações do formulário.

Um `var_dump` em `$_POST` sem preencher os campos vai retornar o seguinte:

```
    array (size=2) 
   'nome' => string '' (length=0)
   'qtde' => string '' (length=0)
```

Ou seja, a variável $_POST não está vazia, ela contém algo. Logo, a única forma de obter este resultado é não enviando o `submit`.

Você pode simular isso abrindo o script PHP no navegador e dando enter na barra de navegação (sem usar a página HTML).

Com relação às outras condições, parece que você fez uma confusão com `else` e `else if`, e a própria lógica parece não atender ao que as respostas (os `echos`) informam.

Então o que fiz foi recriar as condições para que reflitam aquilo que as respostas informam.

A primeira mensagem é de sucesso, e requer que:

- ambas as variáveis estejam setadas (que os campos respectivos existam);
- ambas as variáveis estejam preenchidas (não vazias);

Então é preciso entender a diferença entre setada (`isset`) e vazia (`empty`), e acho que isso vai ficar claro na última condição (e existem vários tópicos muito bons aqui sobre isso, e estou relacionando alguns ao final).

Então esta condição ficou assim:

```
if (isset($_POST['nome']) && isset($_POST['qtde']) &&
        !empty($_POST['nome']) && !empty($_POST['qtde'])) {
            $nome = $_POST['nome'];
            $qtde = $_POST['qtde'];
            echo "Aviso ao representate $nome <br/>
         A equipe com $qtde alunos foi aceita!";
    }
```

A próxima condição é "Prencha os campos", o que significa que eles devem estar setados, porém, vazios.

Então a condição fica assim:

```
else if (isset($_POST['nome']) && isset($_POST['qtde'])
       && empty($_POST['nome']) && empty($_POST['qtde'])) {

                echo "Preencha os campos";
            }
```

Agora nesta última condição ("O campo [nome] nao existe na variavel $_POST") acho que dá pra entender melhor a diferença entre o `isset` e o `empty`.

Veja que, segundo a mensagem, o campo nome **não existe** em `$_POST`, então a condição fica assim:

```
else if (!isset($_POST['nome'])) {

            echo "O campo nome nao existe na variável POST.";
    }
```

Agora, pra você obter esta mensagem, você tem que mudar o `name` do campo nome no formulário, para que ele não seja encontrado por `$_POST`:

```
<input type="text" name="name111">
```

Assim, você atende à condição acima (i.e.: não está setado - em `!isset` o `!` significa `não`)

Você também precisa mudar o texto da resposta para apenas POST, porque com `$_POST` vai dar erro, já que é um `array`. Ou você pode escapar os caracteres, mas a resposta já está grande e não vou entrar nesta questão.

Segue o código normalizado:

teste.html:

```
<form action="alunos.php" method="post">
    <label for="nome">
        <input type="text" name="nme" id="nome">
    </label>
    <label for="qtde">
        <input type="number" id="qtde" name="qtde">
    </label>
    <label for="submit">
        <input type="submit" value="Enviar" id="submit"/>
    </label>
</form>
```

alunos.php:

```
<?php

if (!empty($_POST)) {

    if (isset($_POST['nome']) && isset($_POST['qtde']) &&
        !empty($_POST['nome']) && !empty($_POST['qtde'])) {

            $nome = $_POST['nome'];
            $qtde = $_POST['qtde'];
            echo "Aviso ao representate $nome <br/>
         A equipe com $qtde alunos foi aceita!";
    }
        else if (!isset($_POST['nome'])) {

            echo "O campo nome nao existe na variável POST.";
    }
        else if (isset($_POST['nome']) && isset($_POST['qtde'])
       && empty($_POST['nome']) && empty($_POST['qtde'])) {

                echo "Preencha os campos";
            }
    }

else {

    echo "Não houve submit.";

}
```

Veja funcionando no [Ideone](https://ideone.com/IPQBSM), onde a mensagem é justamente a que você queria, porque no caso não existe `submit`.

Perguntas relacionadas:

[Qual a diferença entre else e elseif?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/57791/qual-a-diferen%c3%a7a-entre-else-e-elseif)

(sei que tem outras, depois vou procurar...)

Answer (score 3):

O fluxo está correto pois o POST vai existir como um array de objetos mesmo que os campos estejam vazios. Por isso o fluxo passa pelo `empty($_POST)`.

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST))
    var_dump($_POST);
    var_dump(empty($_POST));
?>
<form action="tmp.php" method="POST">
<input type="text" name="foo" value="" size="20" />
<input type="submit" value="send" />
</form>
```

Quando submeter, resultará nisso:

```
array(1) {
  ["foo"]=>
  string(0) ""
}
bool(false)
```

Veja que `$_POST` não está vazio, mas os objetos dentro dele sim.

Para criar uma condição de "não houve submit", há soluções diversas.

Uma solução mais simples e lógica é verificar o tamanho do array ao invés de verificar se está vazio.

```
if (isset($_POST) && count($_POST)>0)
```

Comment: +1 exatamente isso,"Veja que $_POST não está vazio, mas os objetos dentro dele sim."

Comment: A resposta do especialista é sempre mais simples e objetiva. +1

Answer (score 0):

Tente assim :

```
if (count($_POST) > 0)
```

A questão é que o `empty()` não esta fazendo a verificação correta e retornando que existe algo no array, quando não existe.

Veja funcionando :[Ideone](https://ideone.com/JgrJ7x)